# HTML5 Audio Pushed through PHP Not Cached

Tags: php, html5-audio

I'm writing a web audio player and i'm having issues with caching being rather unreliable and the only thing that comes to mind is the headers I'm serving.

Due to complications in general and security I have to parse the file through PHP which is fine because it means I can create them on the fly, but the problem that has arisen is that browsers don't seem to cache the audio tracks anymore except on rare occasions, other times they may only cache the first 1/4 of the track. I can't reliably work out what it's caching or why.

The code that serves the file is below. Just for reference, the "EncodeTrack" function only encodes the track if it hasn't already been created, it doesn't do anything if the file already exists.

```
    ## Track Decoder and Streamer
if($_GET['playtrack']) {
    error_log("Dec Start");
    $dectimer = microtime(1);
    ini_set('display_errors', 0);
    $track = trim($_GET['playtrack']);
    preg_match('%^(\w+)\-(\w+)\.(\w+)$%', $track, $trackbits);
    $trackid = $trackbits[1];
    $trackquality = $trackbits[2];
    $trackformat = $trackbits[3];

    $trackarr = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `tracks` NATURAL JOIN `artists` NATURAL JOIN `albums` WHERE `track_hash` = '$trackid' LIMIT 1"));
    $file = "$musicfolder/$trackarr[artist_folder]/$trackarr[album_folder]/$trackarr[track_path]";
    $trackpath = escapeshellarg($file);

    EncodeTrack($trackid, $trackformat, $trackpath, $trackquality);
    $transfile = "tmp/$trackid-$trackquality.$trackformat";

    if(file_exists($transfile)) {
        $filesize = filesize($transfile);
        $file = fopen($transfile, 'r');

        if($_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE']) {
            $partial = 1;

            $range = str_replace('bytes=', '', $_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE']);
            $range = explode(',', $range);
            $range = explode('-', $range[0]);

            if($range[0] === '') {
                $end = $filesize - 1;
                $start = $end - intval($range[0]);
            }elseif($range[1] === '') {
                $start = intval($range[0]);
                $end = $filesize - 1;
            }else{
                $start = intval($range[0]);
                $end = intval($range[1]);
                if ($end >= $filesize || (!$start && (!$end || $end == ($filesize - 1)))) $partial = false; // Invalid range/whole file specified, return whole file
            }      
            $length = $end - $start;

            header("HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content", 1, 206);
            header("Content-Range: bytes $start-$end/$filesize");
            fseek($file, $start);
        }else{
            $length = $filesize;
        }

        $data = fread($file, $filesize);
        fclose($file);

        header("Content-Length: $length");
        header("Content-Type: audio/$trackformat");
        header("Accept-Ranges: bytes");
        header("Expires: Tue, 23 May 2062 10:00:00 GMT");
        header("ETag: $length");
        header("Cache-Control: public");

        echo($data);
    }else{
        header("HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found", 1, 404);
    }

    error_log("Dec Complete - ".round((microtime(1) - $dectimer)*100));
    exit;
}
```

I'm out of ideas what I'm missing here. It may also be something I'm doing wrong in terms of the partial content handling, but as far as I can tell it's sane.

Comment: I had similar problems with video files and in my case the problem was not the code but the companys internal net which prevented byterange requests from being handled properly (I guess because of some firewall settings). Maybe you are suffering the same - if not, keep it in mind nevertheless as streaming can be a real pain and mostly the problems are not the code but the network transfer.

Answer (score 1):

If you suspect something wrong with the partial content handling, let `pecl_http` send the right headers and bytes.

Replace the `if(file_exists($transfile))` block with [http_send_file()](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.http-send-file.php) like this :

```
http_send_file($transfile);
```

Your code is know lighter and less prown to bugs... What's more, [pecl_http](http://pecl.php.net/package/pecl_http) gives you you have free bonus features like `http_throttle()`

Hope this helps !

Comment: The issue with this is that it relies on a third party module and that (for me right now) the module fails to compile.

Comment: @Enverex : what did you try to compile ? sometimes you need php headers package. On Ubuntu see this post for needed commands : http://www.php.net/manual/en/http.install.php#81371

Comment: I'm trying to use the pecl-http package in the Arch AUR. I'm getting - http_message_object.c:517:2: error: ‘zend_class_entry’ has no member named ‘default_properties’ - From what I can tell it's the latest stable version (1.7.1).

Comment: Looks like version 1 (2 isn't actually out yet) isn't compatible with PHP 5.4 which is why I can't compile it.

Comment: @Enverex did you try v1.7.2, they say it is now compatible : http://pecl.php.net/package-info.php?package=pecl_http&version=1.7.2

Comment: I'll try that once it lands in the repos here. I've just tried mod_xsendfile which is basically the same thing but at the Apache level rather than PHP, but I'm still having issues with the audio file not being cached so it's not an issue with my serving code...